# Custom color for specific serie using ngx-charts

Tags: angular, ngx-charts

I'm using the Angular wrapper for D3.js ngx-charts, I have a Bar Vertical Stacked Graph represented but I need the color of the series to be custom when the series has a specific value. Here is an example of how my results are shaped.

```
[{
name: 'Aug. 2018',
series:[{
    name: "Serie 1",
    value: 2500,
    isVirtual: false
},{
    name: "Serie 2",
    value: 250,
    isVirtual: true
},{
    name: "Serie 3",
    value: 20,
    isVirtual: false
},{
    name: "Serie 4",
    value: 25,
    isVirtual: true
},{
    name: "Serie 5",
    value: 2,
    isVirtual: false
}]
},{
name: 'Sep. 2018',
series:[{
    name: "Serie 1",
    value: 2500,
    isVirtual: false
},{
    name: "Serie 2",
    value: 250,
    isVirtual: false
},{
    name: "Serie 3",
    value: 20,
    isVirtual: false
},{
    name: "Serie 4",
    value: 25,
    isVirtual: false
},{
    name: "Serie 5",
    value: 2,
    isVirtual: false
}]
}]
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Could you describe your use case in more details?

Comment: @Marjan In this case I need that for the case of **Serie 2** when `isVirtual` is `true` then show a different color.

Comment: Your series (lines) in this case are the dates. Serie 1, Serie, 2, etc, are just points on those lines, and you can not change the color of a single point.

Comment: @Marjan Not possible due to wrapper incapacity or because D3 does not allow it?

Answer (score 0):

I face the same problem. The solution is to iterate on each object of your array and to build a custom Array of colors depending on your "isVirtual" value. After that you can transmit your "color array" to your ngx-charts using the [scheme] input.

EDIT: my bad, the solution I propose only work for non stacked data...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thanks for sharing your answer with the community. Could you please provide a small code example so it is even more clear what you mean?

Comment: Exactly if you can provide an example could be nice. Thanks for answer

Answer (score 0):

One solution, not optimal but works. Precondition is that your series names are unique. Unfortunately the bar component does not seem to parse multiple parameters of each element, only the name.

Template:

```
    <ngx-charts-bar-vertical-stacked
                            [results]="results"
                            [customColors]="customColors" ></ngx-charts-bar-vertical-stacked>
```

Typescript:

```
customColors = (name) => {
    // simple example, in your case you have to have nested searching or all series combined in one additional array
    let serie= this.results.find(serie => serie.name == name);

    if (serie.isVirtual) {
      return "#<<hexcode>>";
    } else {
      return "#<<hexcode>>";  
    }
  }
```